# Preload SKTextures for a View Controller that won't be presented for a while?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, scenekit

I know about preloading SKTextures to speed up the Scene initialisation

e.g.

```swift
SKTexture.preloadWithCompletionHandler { 
    // Now everything you put into the texture atlas has been loaded in memory
}
```

However, what I'm struggling with is that my app mainly uses UIKit View Controllers, however, one of them has a SceneKit view with skyboxes and textures that I've been using SKTexture objects for.

When the use tabs to this particular view controller, for the first time, there is a massive 4 second pause.

Once everything's loaded, the user can tab around with no lag to any view controllers in the app, including returning to the SceneKit one.

Because the SceneKit ViewController is NEVER the first view controller to be displayed when the app is first launched, it hasn't even been instantiated from the storyboard or loaded into view in order to execute a

```swift
SKTexture.preloadWithCompletionHandler {}
```

So, can anyone please advise the best way to do this? I wondered about static methods and static variables so that in the App Delegate I could call those, but that felt dirty and broke 'Encapsulation'.

Is there a better way?

NOT WORKING EXAMPLE CODE:

In AppDelegate didLaunch

```swift
sceneKitViewController.preloadTextures()
```

in sceneKitViewController (the SceneKit View Controller that is not the first VC being presented:

```swift
    static var daySkyboxPX:             SKTexture?
    static var daySkyboxNX:             SKTexture?
    static var daySkyboxPY:             SKTexture?
    static var daySkyboxNY:             SKTexture?
    static var daySkyboxPZ:             SKTexture?
    static var daySkyboxNZ:             SKTexture?

    static var overcastSkyboxPX:        SKTexture?
    static var overcastSkyboxNX:        SKTexture?
    static var overcastSkyboxPY:        SKTexture?
    static var overcastSkyboxNY:        SKTexture?
    static var overcastSkyboxPZ:        SKTexture?
    static var overcastSkyboxNZ:        SKTexture?

    static var nightSkyboxPX:           SKTexture?
    static var nightSkyboxNX:           SKTexture?
    static var nightSkyboxPY:           SKTexture?
    static var nightSkyboxNY:           SKTexture?
    static var nightSkyboxPZ:           SKTexture?
    static var nightSkyboxNZ:           SKTexture?


    static func preloadTextures()
    {
        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPX = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dpx")
        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNX = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dnx")
        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPY = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dpy")
        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNY = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dny")
        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPZ = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dpz")
        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNZ = SKTexture(imageNamed: "dnz")

        sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPX = SKTexture(imageNamed: "opx")
        sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNX = SKTexture(imageNamed: "onx")
        sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPY = SKTexture(imageNamed: "opy")
        sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNY = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ony")
        sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPZ = SKTexture(imageNamed: "opz")
        sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNZ = SKTexture(imageNamed: "onz")

        sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPX = SKTexture(imageNamed: "npx")
        sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNX = SKTexture(imageNamed: "nnx")
        sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPY = SKTexture(imageNamed: "npy")
        sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNY = SKTexture(imageNamed: "nny")
        sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPZ = SKTexture(imageNamed: "npz")
        sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNZ = SKTexture(imageNamed: "nnz")

        SKTexture.preload([sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPX!,
                           sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNX!,
                           sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPY!,
                           sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNY!,
                           sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPZ!,
                           sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNZ!,
                           sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPX!,
                           sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNX!,
                           sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPY!,
                           sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNY!,
                           sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPZ!,
                           sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNZ!,
                           sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPX!,
                           sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNX!,
                           sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPY!,
                           sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNY!,
                           sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPZ!,
                           sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNZ!], withCompletionHandler: {} )

        sceneKitViewController.daySkybox? = [sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPX!,
                                        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNX!,
                                        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPY!,
                                        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNY!,
                                        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxPZ!,
                                        sceneKitViewController.daySkyboxNZ!]

        sceneKitViewController.overcastSkybox? = [sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPX!,
                                             sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNX!,
                                             sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPY!,
                                             sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNY!,
                                             sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxPZ!,
                                             sceneKitViewController.overcastSkyboxNZ!]

        sceneKitViewController.nightSkybox? = [sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPX!,
                                       sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNX!,
                                       sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPY!,
                                       sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNY!,
                                       sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxPZ!,
                                       sceneKitViewController.nightSkyboxNZ!]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try loadViewIfNeeded() - If that doesn't meet your needs, you could create a singleton (like GameNodes or Data) and load nodes/graphics during init, then reference from your scenekit view controller(s).  I generally put heavy lifting for Nodes there in once place for all my view controllers to reference in this type of situation. Some don't recommend singleton solutions and I agree, but in this case it has worked for me a number of times.

Answer (score 0):

For better efficiency don't use `SKTexture` objects in SceneKit unless it's necessary. Instead you can provide SceneKit with a file path or URL:

```swift
let path = Bundle.main.pathForImageResource("dpx")
```

And then use SceneKit API to preload resources, for instance [`prepare(_:shouldAbortBlock:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522798-prepare).